# Devexpress Filter Control Clear Filter C#

Tags: c#, filter, controls, devexpress

[image: SampleScreenShot]

Is there an event when I click the X button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such event, but it is possible to handle a related event, instead. The solution is descrived in DevExpress knowledge base: [Which event is fired when the [x] button in the filter panel is clicked?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A1243.aspx)